# Query for count on join table

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have this join table

```
                                Table "public.pic_tags"
     Column |  Type  | Collation | Nullable |               Default
    --------+--------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------
     id     | bigint |           | not null | nextval('pic_tags_id_seq'::regclass)
     tag_id | bigint |           |          |
     pic_id | uuid   |           |          |
```

And I have these two tables

```
                                 Table "public.pics"
        Column        |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default
----------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id                   | uuid                        |           | not null |
 description          | text                        |           |          |
 asset                | character varying(255)      |           |          |
```

and

```
                          Table "public.tags"
 Column |  Type  | Collation | Nullable |             Default
--------+--------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------
 id     | bigint |           | not null | nextval('tags_id_seq'::regclass)
 name   | text   |           | not null |
```

So my question is if I know what the name of a tag is, how do I query how many pics there are for the given tag with name of X?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You don't really have a dot in your table names, do you?

Comment: do you mean the `public` name space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `JOIN` an `COUNT` will show what you want:

```
select count(*)
from tag t
join pic_tags pt on pt.tag_id = t.id
where t.name = 'X'
```

Comment: is that so complex that you gave an answer ?